# Google is unable to render and index my serverside blazor components

Tags: c#, blazor-server-side, google-search-console, asp.net-core-3.1

Google is unable to index my serverside blazor components.

I include serverside blazor component to a razor page with the following code:

```
@(await Html.RenderComponentAsync<WEKA.Components.Sortiment>
    (RenderMode.Server))
```

When I enter a page URL with included blazor serverside component to a test console https://search.google.com/test/mobile-friendly, the components do not get rendered and google mobile search shows following errors:

> [2020-01-08T09:25:45.024Z] Information: Normalizing '_blazor' to
>   'http://www.mywebsite.com/_blazor'.
>   http://www.mywebsite.com/_framework/blazor.server.js:1    00:08.000
>   [2020-01-08T09:25:45.061Z] Warning: Error from HTTP request. 0: .
>   http://www.mywebsite.com/_framework/blazor.server.js:1    00:18.000
>   [2020-01-08T09:25:45.070Z] Error: Connection disconnected with error
>   'Error'.
>   http://www.mywebsite.com/_framework/blazor.server.js:1    00:19.000
>   [2020-01-08T09:25:45.071Z] Error: Error
>   http://www.mywebsite.com/_framework/blazor.server.js:15   00:19.000
>
> Uncaught (in promise) Error: Cannot send data if the connection is not
>   in the 'Connected' State. at e.send
>   (http://www.mywebsite.com/_framework/blazor.server.js:1:42313) at
>   e.sendMessage
>   (http://www.mywebsite.com/_framework/blazor.server.js:1:15469) at
>   e.sendWithProtocol
>   (http://www.mywebsite.com/_framework/blazor.server.js:1:15531) at
>   http://www.mywebsite.com/_framework/blazor.server.js:1:16198 at new
>   Promise () at e.invoke
>   (http://www.mywebsite.com/_framework/blazor.server.js:1:15996) at
>   e.
>   (http://www.mywebsite.com/_framework/blazor.server.js:15:29666) at
>   http://www.mywebsite.com/_framework/blazor.server.js:15:28968 at
>   Object.next
>   (http://www.mywebsite.com/_framework/blazor.server.js:15:29073) at
>   http://www.mywebsite.com/_framework/blazor.server.js:15:27986
>   http://www.mywebsite.com/_framework/blazor.server.js:0

Anything can be done about that? Without changing `RenderMode.Server` to anything else?